# SharePoint o365/online - This site can't be reached

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I try to open my SharePoint online site, I am getting this error message as "**This site can't be reached**".

Also I am not able to open SharePoint Admin Center.

I tried in both Internet Explorer and Chrome browser but still the same issue. Anybody has any idea about this.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you ping it?

Comment: can you access it https://admin.microsoft.com? or https://nameoftenant-admin.sharepoint.com

Comment: @Waqas. No I am not able to access mytenantadminname.sharepoint.com . Getting the same error message.

Comment: @Derek.  I will try to ping and i will let you know the response..thanks

Comment: try it using mobile phone's network data or outside of your corporate firewall

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if the URL of the SharePoint site is correct.
2. Check if the licenses in O365 are expired.
3. Clear the cache in IE.
4. Add the SharePoint online site into the trusted site in IE.

And you also could follow the troubleshooting steps in the article below.

[Fixing Microsoft Site can't be reached error in Chrome.](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/08/26/fixing-microsoft-site-cant-be-reached-error-in-chrome/)

If the issue still exists and you can access the Microsoft 365 admin center, then you can submit a service request like the picture below.

[image]